# Most efficient way to handle uploading to Postgres database CSV ending with 2 newlines

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am handling large (>>1e6 rows) `.csv` files that may erroneously end in 2 newline chars instead of 1 (roughly 1% may have this error).

They are downloaded as `.gz`, unzipped, then uploaded to a Postgres database with the below code.

The extra newline causes an error on the `COPY` command. The [psql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) state a `[ WHERE condition ]` clause can be added, but I haven't been able to make it ignore a null row like I intend.

---

I am looking for the most efficient way to add to my uploading process (ie. doesn't read the entire csv again) to remove this extra newline.

Unzip:

```py
import shutil
def unzip_gz(file_path, new_file_path):
    with gzip.open(file_path, "rb") as f_in:
        with open(new_file_path, "wb") as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

To db:

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE table_name;
COPY table_name
FROM file_path
WITH (FORMAT CSV);
COMMIT WORK;
```

Comment: 1) There is no `PSQL` database, there is a `psql` client program that can access a `Postgres/Postgresql` database. 2) You will need to clean the CSV file before you import it or have whatever is creating the file not add the extra newline.

Comment: What would be the fastest way to do this (ie. not read the entire file)